# NoSuchMethodError when casting body to a specific type

Tags: java, jackson, rest-assured

I have an endpoint that returns number as result of a request. But when I call a method that is supposed to parse body to a specific type it throws an exception.
Transitive dependencies included by `RestAssured` of `Jackson` are on `1.9.2 version`.

```
  Long cardId = response.getBody().as(Long.class);
```

- Maven: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.2
- Maven: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:1.9.2
- Maven: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.2
- Maven: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:1.9.2

  ```
   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findAndRegisterModules()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper;
      at com.jayway.restassured.mapper.factory.DefaultJackson2ObjectMapperFactory.create(DefaultJackson2ObjectMapperFactory.java:27)
      at com.jayway.restassured.mapper.factory.DefaultJackson2ObjectMapperFactory.create(DefaultJackson2ObjectMapperFactory.java:25)
      at com.jayway.restassured.mapper.factory.ObjectMapperFactory$create.call(Unknown Source)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
      at com.jayway.restassured.internal.path.json.mapping.JsonPathJackson2ObjectDeserializer.createJackson2ObjectMapper(JsonPathJackson2ObjectDeserializer.groovy:34)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:207)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
      at com.jayway.restassured.internal.path.json.mapping.JsonPathJackson2ObjectDeserializer.deserialize(JsonPathJackson2ObjectDeserializer.groovy:41)
      at com.jayway.restassured.path.json.mapping.JsonPathObjectDeserializer$deserialize.call(Unknown Source)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
      at com.jayway.restassured.internal.mapping.Jackson2Mapper.deserialize(Jackson2Mapper.groovy:60)
      at com.jayway.restassured.mapper.ObjectMapper$deserialize.call(Unknown Source)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:122)
      at com.jayway.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping.parseWithJackson2(ObjectMapping.groovy:188)
      at com.jayway.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping$parseWithJackson2$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:191)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:211)
      at com.jayway.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping.deserialize(ObjectMapping.groovy:51)
      at com.jayway.restassured.internal.mapping.ObjectMapping$deserialize.call(Unknown Source)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
      at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
      at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.as(RestAssuredResponseOptionsGroovyImpl.groovy:206)
      at com.jayway.restassured.internal.RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.as(RestAssuredResponseOptionsImpl.java:153)
  ```

  I've already tried to include `jackson annotation`, `databind` and `core` but it didn't help.

Comment: Give more stacktrace. Your code is probably using the wrong version of the Jackson dependency.

Comment: what the version of dependency?

Comment: Yes, this is what I expected to see. You are using RestAssured, which has a transitive dependency on Jackson. However, you also have a direct dependency on Jackson, but on a version which RestAssured is not compatible with (or another of your dependencies uses a different version of Jackson). Use `mvn dependency:tree` to see what's going on and fix your pom.xml.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't see any more `jackson` dependencies in the `pom` file. However, there are some more of `codehaus`, but I'm not sure does it really matter.

Comment: codehaus version is for Jackson 1.x. Unless you know for sure it is needed, I would drop it -- these are old versions. Error messages, on the other hand, indicates that some library is expecting a newer Jackson 2.x version (com.fasterxml); and there definitely is some kind of version discrepancy between what the library was compiled against (newer version) and what is being found from classpath (older).

Comment: @ashur It's should be mostly a cause by class of another transitive dependency that's been searched for. As said, did your try to run `mvn dependency:tree` ? It should give some clue. Also if you use an IDE like Eclipse/IntelliJ just also make sure by doing Ctrl+Shift+T / Ctrl+Shift+N and N , respectively to check for the class' occurrences as well?

Comment: What's weird is that Jackson 1 and Jackson 2 should coexist happily. Which would suggest what StaxMan mentioned that RestAssured is getting confused by this.